# Google Colab does not apply the changes I make to the code in my local directory

Tags: git, google-colaboratory

I am working with a cloned repo from git for a project, and I am making changes to the cloned files constantly. I ran into a problem recently: no matter what I change in the local files from the cloned github project, those changes wouldn't apply to the colab notebook (for example if I add a print here and there, nothing would print, but the functions are called).

I began facing this problem after trying to push all my files from my colab to git, because I know they are not being saved if I only save the notebook, and I followed the commands from here:

https://navan0.medium.com/how-to-push-files-into-github-from-google-colab-379fd0077aa8

I am not sure, but I might have started some multithreading, and I am not good at dealing with that. No matter what I change, the changes won't appear to have taken place, and I must push the changes to git and then clone it again and then they would appear. Also, I must terminate the runtime, because I cannot get rid of the directory with `!rm -rf directory_name`, it will still appear in files. If I re-run same command, it says directory does not exist.

I am pretty sure it's multithreading or some forked processes. I would like to terminate that.

Link to my notebook:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1WMaDcEwOdPEsZL65nU_T4Ps9tIkyPY5v?usp=sharing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's nothing colab-specific going on here -- any long-lived Python session would behave the same way.

The issue you're hitting is that python imports are *idempotent*: once you `import foo`, any further attempts to `import foo` are a no-op. (Python caches the results of imports in `sys.modules`.) So if you import a module, edit it, and import again, you won't see your edits.

You'd see the same if you were in the python REPL, and attempted to edit a file and re-import it.

You have two easy ways out:

- restart the python process; in Colab, this is ctrl-m . or `Runtime` -> `Restart runtime`.
- you can use [`importlib.reload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload) to re-import your updated code.

`reload` is great, but I'll warn you that it has many sharp edges, and it's quite easy to trick yourself. If your setup is reasonably quick (eg you don't have to recreate a bunch of large objects in memory), restarting is a great way to maintain your sanity.